# Does using Realm encryption's functionality have ramifications for app store submission?

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store, realm

I have an app using Realm and am using its encryption functionality (https://news.realm.io/news/tim-oliver-realm-cocoa-tutorial-on-encryption-with-realm/)

Which states this:

> Legal Considerations
>
> When distributing apps via Apple’s App Store, there are certain legal
>   obligations in regards to export compliance for apps that incorporate
>   encryption.
>
> This usually involves declaring to Apple that your app incorporates
>   encryption, and depending on the nature of the data encrypted, filing
>   a request for export registration with the United States Bureau of
>   Industry and Security.
>
> Certain exemptions from needing to register for most of the common
>   encryption use-cases (such as user authentication) were introduced in
>   2010. As such, it is only necessary to declare to Apple that the app incorporates encryption during the submission process and nothing
>   more.
>
> More information about U.S. export compliance as well as the specific
>   exemptions can be found on the Bureau of Industry and Security’s
>   website.
>
> Disclaimer: The information in this section should not be taken as
>   formal legal advice. Your specific use-cases for encryption may vary.
>   If you are unsure as to whether your app falls within the export
>   compliance exemptions, please contact an attorney.

In one part it says

> "...depending on the nature of the data encrypted, filing a request
>   for export registration with the United States Bureau of Industry and
>   Security"

and:

> " As such, it is only necessary to declare to Apple that the app
>   incorporates encryption during the submission process and nothing
>   more."

These two statements are contradictory to me, the first saying filing a request for export IS needed, but depending on the nature of the date. But the second statement contradicts this by saying "it is only necessary to declare to Apple that the app incorporates encryption during the submission process and nothing more."

What is the actual situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two statements aren't contradictory. If the exemptions from the Bureau of Industry and Security’s policy apply to your app, it's only necessary to declare to Apple that your app incorporates encryption. If your app doesn't fall within one of the exemptions you must file a request for export registration with the United States Bureau of Industry and Security, as well as declaring to Apple that the app incorporates encryption.